# MYSQL: How to limit inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, limit, inner-join

I need some help with my query.
I have 2 tables:

```
all: art|serie
sootv: name|art|foo
```

I need to get result like name|serie.
My query is:

```
SELECT t2.NAME,
    t1.serie
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM `all`
    WHERE `serie` LIKE '$serie'
    ) t1
INNER JOIN sootv t2
    ON t1.art = t2.art;
```

it works, but `sootv` table contains data like

```
name|art|foo
abc | 1 | 5
abc | 1 | 6
```

I get 2 same results. Its not what i need.
Help me please - how i can get only one result: abc|1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **[`DISTINCT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)** on `SELECT` clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.NAME,
       t1.serie
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM `all`
    WHERE `serie` LIKE '$serie'
    ) t1
INNER JOIN sootv t2
    ON t1.art = t2.art;
```

or try optimizing it

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.NAME,
       t1.serie
FROM `all` t1
      INNER JOIN sootv t2
          ON t1.art = t2.art
WHERE t1.`serie` LIKE '$serie'
```